# No transaction available in thread - cannot process remove call

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

There's a few questions to the same topic around, but none of them seem to fit my problem.

We have some cleanup tasks for our database, and they can result in very long transactions if we don't split them up manually (hours!). Partly because related data needs to be cleaned out from other places that really don't need to run in a transaction, partly because some querying is necessary to assert which data needs to be deleted, and partly because the operation potentially affects hundreds of thousands of rows.

So just using @Transactional annotations doesn't cut it, I have to fall back on defining transaction scopes manually with TransactionTemplates to get nice, confined and short transactions that don't lock up tables.

I have seen similar to the above error before during the current refactor, and could identify and eliminate the causes without much issue (a flush of the entity manager at the wrong time, or entities accessed outside their transaction context, things like that).

But now I'm left with one instance that has me stomped, and I cannot figure out why it happens. The code I was left with after commenting out everything else is very simple. There's the TransactionTemplate instances I'm using:

```
private val readTransaction = org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate(
        transactionManager,
        DefaultTransactionDefinition().apply {
            isReadOnly = true
            propagationBehavior = TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NEVER
        })

private val writeTransaction = org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate(
        transactionManager,
        DefaultTransactionDefinition().apply {
            isReadOnly = false
            propagationBehavior = TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NEVER
        })
```

And then there's the few lines of code that produce the error:

```
    internal fun emptyTrashedImages(olderThan: LocalDateTime) {
        // extract all trashsets
        val trashSets = readTransaction.execute {
            imageSetRepository.findAllByCameraIdIsNull()
                    .filter { it.time < olderThan }
                    .map { it.id }
        }!!

        // Other operations using trashSets that I commented out and still receive the error

        // this is where the error happens  
        writeTransaction.execute { imageSetRepository.deleteByIdIn(trashSets) }
    }
```

I'm reading out the IDs of the things I need deleted in one transaction, and store them as a simple list of Longs (as you can see, I'm not keeping any entities around).

Then I open a new write transaction in which I simply call a repository method:

```
interface ImageSetRepository : CrudRepository<ImageSet, Long> {
    // not the only method in here, but the only one invoked to produce the error
    fun deleteByIdIn(ids: List<Long>)
}
```

And that's it. I'm doing basically the same thing at other points in the process to other tables, and it works without issue. But when I call that repository method, I just get "No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call"

Can anybody tell me how to fix this? Please don't say "just use @Transactional" unless you can tell me a way to cleanly separate the operations into different transactions that *finish* before the next one (not suspend, that just leads to locked up tables somewhere down the line).

EDIT:

I simplified the code further by just passing a short list of IDs I know exist in the database, like so:

```
internal fun emptyTrashedImages(olderThan: LocalDateTime) {
    writeTransaction.execute {  imageSetRepository.deleteAllByIdIn(listOf(19923415, 19923416)) }
}
```

The error still occurs. However, if I change that line to delete just one row, like

```
writeTransaction.execute { imageSetRepository.deleteById(19923415) }
```

It works. So there's something about how Spring-Data implements the deleteAllByIdIn() method that somehow doesn't work in this context. Since other operations structured the same way use queries defined by myself, I guess I'll try that next.

Result: Nope, doesn't work either. Well, slightly different worded error message (delete requires a transaction). In other words, it does in fact look as though no transaction exists at this point. Which is weird, since I'm executing the query inside one. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that even if you manage transactions manually, the method still needs an @Transactional annotation. In this case, I used @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER, since I don't want anybody to invoke it with an ongoing transaction).

There is another pitfall here though, in that methods called on this simply ignore that annotation because the proxy isn't invoked. And since I explicitly want to not have any ongoing transactions, this means that the method doing the transaction *has* to be invoked from another class. This annoying detail required me to restructure my code a little, but it's survivable.

It's got a certain logic to it, but it's also somewhat bamboozling. *Why* exactly do I need an @Transactional annotation on a method in which I invoke a TransactionTemplate manually? Any comments on that would be welcome.